# Cannot post error react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I get an blank page with an error *Cannot POST /registration/step-two*.

I'm trying to create multistep registration. Render function of my main component is as follows:

```
render() {
    const languageReg = this.props.currentLanguage.default.registrationPage;


    let stepOne = (this.props.params.id == 'step-one') ? <RegistrationFormStepOne actionSaveUser={this.props.actionSaveUser} currentLanguage={languageReg}/> : "";
    let stepTwo = (this.props.params.id == 'step-two') ? <RegistrationFormStepTwo actionSaveUser={this.props.actionSaveUser} currentLanguage={languageReg}/> : "";

    return (
        <div className="sidebar-menu-container" id="sidebar-menu-container">

            <div className="sidebar-menu-push">

                <div className="sidebar-menu-overlay"></div>

                <div className="sidebar-menu-inner">
                    <div className="contact-form registrationForm">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-offset-right-1">
                                    {stepOne}
                                    {stepTwo}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In RegistrationFormStepOne I have function on click as follows :

```
handleClick(){
    let data = {name: "stepOne", values: [this.state.user]};
    this.context.router.push("/registration/step-two");
}
```

When I click on this button, the url is like it should be `http://localhost:3000/registration/step-two` but I'm getting `Cannot POST /registration/step-two` error.

When I type direct http://localhost:3000/registration/step-two it works fine.

I'm using [reactNoConfiguration App](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html)

Any advice?

Comment: when you type url, its a GET request. For POST, request, your server should accept POST request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was in the handle click function. I forgot to prevent default. I changed it to :

```
handleClick(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     let data = {name: "stepOne", values: [this.state.user]};
     this.context.router.push("/registration/step-two");
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, I made the same mistake