# React.js 'Unexpected token' < when using form tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, semantic-ui-react

I've been making a web app using mern stack with babel, webpack, redux and semantic-ui-react.

But I got an error saying

> "Unexpected token <" in bundle.js.

This error only occurs when I send a request clicking a button in form tag. If I make the page without a form tag, it works fine without any error.

This is my codes in React.

```
handleUpload(title, contents, userId) {
  return this.props.createPostRequest(title, contents, userId).then(
    () => {
      if(this.props.post.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        alert('Your post is saved successfully.');
        browserHistory.push('/');
        return true;
      } else {
        alert('Save Fail: ' + this.props.post.failReason);
        return false;
      }
    }
  );
}

render() {
  return(
    <div className="Write">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <Form>
        <Container text>
          <Form.Input label='Title' fluid name='title' placeholder='title'
            value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <input/>
          </Form.Input>
          <Form.TextArea rows='20' name='contents' placeholder='Write here!'
            value={this.state.contents} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <textarea/>
          </Form.TextArea>
          <br/>
          <Button.Group>
            <Button color='orange' as={Link} to='/'>Cancel</Button>
            <Button.Or/>
            <Button positive onClick={this.handleUpload}>Save</Button>
          </Button.Group>
        </Container>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I type letters and click the save button, I can see an alert message saying

> Your post is saved successfully..

And also the data I put is saved in mongodb. But after I click ok, the url changes from `'localhost:3000/post/write`' to '`localhost:3000/post/write?title=blah&contents=blah`'. blah in the url is what I put in input tags. Then console says

> Unxpected token <.

But, if I don't use a form tag in above codes, it works fine, which I totally have no idea what's wrong about.. The Form tag is from semantic-ui-react. So I need it. If I don't use Form, it would work fine but I should give up the design provided from semantic-ui.

Is there anyone who knows about this? I guess it's related to the HTTP POST in form tags that make trouble for react.js to understand bundle.js in index.html after the server-side handles the post request from that form tag.

Comment: Are you using redux as well?

Comment: The URL behavior you've described is of a form without method="post" specified (it's submitting using the form default of GET, which posts the values to the querystring).

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem Yes I am.

Comment: @RobWilkins I tried method="post" in a form tag as you said, then the console says "Cannot POST /post/write"

Comment: A similar error is discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724481/cannot-post-error-react-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

```
handleSubmit = (e) => e.preventDefault()

<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
```

#### Why?

By default, an HTML form will make GET request to the current URI on submit, see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3).  Also by default, a button in a form will submit it:

http://codepen.io/levithomason/pen/RpEwWP

```
<form onsubmit="alert('submitted!')">
  <button>I'll submit</button>
  <button>Me too</button>
</form>
```

What is happening is, React is rendering a `<form />` with some `<button />`s inside of it and when you click them, it is making a `GET` request to the current URI with the form data.

Going out on a limb, I bet your local server that is serving your app doesn't have a handler to accept this request.  Going further, I bet it also has a fallback that responds with the `index.html` on unknown requests.  This is commonplace for single page apps to allow the app's soft router to handle routing, rather than the server.  This is probably causing your request for `bundle.js` to actually receive the `index.html`, hence the unexpected token.

Since you've stated:

> ...if I don't use a form tag in above codes, it works fine...

Simply preventing the form submit should solve it for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. thanks! It works fine now.